# The first layers while printing look strange

Tags: prusa-i3, quality, geeetech

I own a Geeetech i3 Pro W and I started printing today. Amazing how it works.

I just recognized while printing my first bigger model something very strange: At the beginning some parts are missing and there are huge holes. However when I keep it printing the following layers "fix" the issue. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I almost forgot to mention that I think I'm using that PLA, the bed has a temperature of 60 °C and the extruder 200 °C.

Here are two pictures after about 1 layer and after about 4 layers:

[image: first layer]

[image: fourth layer]

Comment: You're having bed adhesion issues. Are you sure you've leveled the bed correctly? The distance to bed for the initial layer is critical.

Comment: I used a peace of paper, might be I still need to lower it more. It fits now easy everywhere without having much space (I haven't tried it, but I don't think that two layers would fit).

Comment: When I level my bed, the paper drags quite a bit. I like a lot of squish which gives good adhesion. You can only get good squish if you have the distance tight. The drag is enough I can't push the paper under the nozzle, I have to pull it both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first layer image it can be seen that your nozzle to bed distance is just too large:

1. the lines of deposited filament e.g. in the brim are not touching,
2. deposited filament lines are not "squished" or "flattened" to the build plate,
3. filament is cutting off corners as it is dragged while being hot and not stuck to the bed,
4. filament leaves the nozzle in "blobs"; it sort of free flows from the nozzle as the bed is too far to give resistance.

Use the plain paper technique while levelling the bed. The paper should give a slight drag/resistance when pulled/pushed. Proper levelling and a proper nozzle to bed distance for the first layer are essential for successful prints.

There is also an option to integrally lower the print level in the slicer software, but it is advised to properly level the bed (hardware solution) instead of using software tricks to sort out the problem.